# Equivalent characterization of differentiable quasi-concave functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis

I am looking for a proof for the following statement:

> Suppose $f: A \to \mathbb R$, where $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$, is continuously differentiable on $A$ which has the property that for all $x_2, x_1 \in A$,
> $$f(x_2)\geq f(x_1) \implies (x_2-x_1)f'(x_1)\geq0$$
> Prove that $f(x)$ is quasi-concave.

**Attempt:**

We need to show that for all $\theta \in [0,1]$, $f(\theta x_2 + (1-\theta)x_1) \geq f(x_1)$. For contradiction, suppose not. So, $\exists \,\,\bar \theta \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_1) > f(\bar\theta x_2 + (1-\bar\theta)x_1)$.

Let $z\equiv \bar\theta x_2 + (1-\bar\theta)x_1$. From the property of $f$ stated above:
$$(x_1-z)f'(z) \geq 0, \quad (x_2-z)f'(z) \geq 0.$$
Since, $x_i\leq z\leq x_j$, $f'(z)=0$.

This is where I am stuck. I found some sources which use MVT hereafter to prove. But I didn't understand those proofs very well. I was trying to use converse of MVT but realized that it's wrong (i.e., I cannot claim that there exists some $z_1, z_2$ such that $z$ lies between them and $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$).

I want to be able to show somehow that $f'(z)=0$ is a contradiction to the property above.

---

EDIT: based on the posted answer, does this work:
Case1: $f(x_2)\geq f(x_1)$ and $x_2>x_1$

Let $x_n$ be an increasing sequence in $[x_1,x_2]$ such that $f(x_n) \geq f(x_1)$ for all $n$. Existence of such a sequence is without loss of generality as there will be finite or infinite points which satisfy $f(x_n) \geq f(x_1)$ and we are just taking an ordered sequence of them.

Since $[x_1,x_2]$ is bounded from above, this sequence will converge. Since the set is also a closed set, the sequence will converge in the set. Let $z$ be the limit point of this sequence. Clearly $z \neq x_2$. So there is an interval $(z,x_2]$ such that for all $x$ in this interval $f(x)<f(x_1)$. As discussed above and in the answer posted, $f'(x)$ for all $x$ in
$(z,x_2]$ is zero and thus the right limit of $f(z)$ is $f(x_2)$ which contradicts continuity.

Answer (score -1):

Recall the definition of quasiconcavity:$$
f((1 - t) x_1 + tx_2) \geqslant \min(f(x_1), f(x_2)),
$$
where $x_1, x_2 \in A$ and $t \in (0, 1)$. In fact, the condition can be further slightly weakened.

> **Proposition:** If $f \in C([a, b])$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$, and for any $x_1, x_2 \in [a, b]$,\begin{gather*}
> f(x_2) \geqslant f(x_1) \implies (x_2 - x_1) f'(x_1) \geqslant 0, \tag{1}
> \end{gather*}
> then $f$ is quasiconcave on $[a, b]$.

*Proof:* Suppose otherwise, then there exist $x_1, x_2 \in [a, b]$ with $x_1 < x_2$, and $t \in (0, 1)$ such that$$
f((1 - t) x_1 + tx_2) < \min(f(x_1), f(x_2)).
$$
Denote $x_3 = (1 - t) x_1 + tx_2$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_3$, there exists $δ > 0$ with $f(x) < \min(f(x_1), f(x_2))$ for $x \in (x_3 - δ, x_3 + δ)$.

**Case 1:** $f(x_1) \leqslant f(x_2)$.

Define $y_1 = \sup\{x \in [x_1, x_3] \mid f(x) \geqslant f(x_1)\}$, then $y_1 \leqslant x_3 - δ$. On the one hand, for any $x \in (y_1, x_3)$, since$$
f(x) < f(x_1) = \min(f(x_1), f(x_2)),
$$
then (1) implies that$$
(x_1 - x) f'(x) \geqslant 0, \quad (x_2 - x) f'(x) \geqslant 0,
$$
thus $f'(x) = 0$. Therefore, $f$ is constant on $[y_1, x_3]$ by Lagrange's theorem, and $f(y_1) = f(x_3)$.

On the other hand, the definition of $y_1$ shows that there exists $\{u_n\} \subseteq [x_1, y_1)$ with $f(u_n) \geqslant f(x_1)$ for all $n$ and $u_n → y_1$ ($n → ∞$), hence the continuity of $f$ at $y_1$ implies that$$
f(y_1) = \lim_{n → ∞} f(u_n) \geqslant f(x_1) > f(x_3),
$$
a contradiction.

**Case 2:** $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$.

Define $y_2 = \inf\{x \in [x_3, x_2] \mid f(x) \geqslant f(x_2)\}$. The rest follows analogously to Case 1.

---

The appended discussion in the question has an error: For the selected sequence $\{x_n\}$, it can happen that $z = x_2$ as there is no other restriction.

Comment: I don't know why this post has a downvote. This answer seems to capture the intuition. But some doubts. Let me ask only one first: we have shown that for all x in (y1,x3), the derivative is zero and function is constant. How to we invoke roller's theorem to say that f(y1)=f(x3)?

Comment: I think we will need to use continuity to show this and not rolle's theorem. If we can use rolle's please clarify a little as I am unable to see this.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see it. I think you are using reverse of MVT. The theorem says that there exists a point where that equality holds. It doesn't say that if there is a point where derivative is zero then f(a)=f(b). f(X)=x^3 is a counter example. In any case your method has provided a good hint. I was able to make some progress and will keep trying. Please feel free to edit your answer if you do get it.

Comment: Yeah I know about MathJax in comments. Just that I am using mobile to just avoiding that as it would take time

Comment: Taking cue from your answer I have made an attempt. If you think it's correct please drop an message. If I don't get any better answers I will reward the bounty to you as your answer gave me an important hint.

Comment: Thanks for handling the downvote. And valid point about z=x2. I still don't know about lagrange's. Can you provide some references please.

Comment: @Dayne It seems that different texts use different names for this theorem. Anyway, see [mean-value theorem](https://planetmath.org/MeanvalueTheorem) (what I refer to as Lagrange's) and [its proof](http://planetmath.org/ProofOfMeanValueTheorem). See also [extended mean-value theorem](https://planetmath.org/ExtendedMeanvalueTheorem) and [its proof](http://planetmath.org/ProofOfExtendedMeanvalueTheorem).

Comment: I am sorry. I still think you are using reverse of MVT. You have shown that f'(x) is zero. That does not imply, from MVT, that f(y1)=f(x3). Although this can be shown easily with continuity of f.

Comment: @Dayne I've never heard of “reverse of MVT,” and this *is* a direct implication by the theorem:$$f(x_3)-f(y_1)=f'(ξ)(x_3-y_1)=0,$$where $ξ\in(y_1,x_3)$.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^3$. Take $\xi =0, y_1=-1, x_3=1$. So $\xi \in (y_1,x_3)$. Now use your version of MVT and you'll get $f(y_1)=f(x_3)$, which isn't true.

Comment: This is because MVT doesn't say that this equation holds for any fixed $\xi$. It just says that there exists one. For a given $\xi$ this cannot be written.

Comment: In any case, this part was not relevant to your proof. As I mentioned this part can be shown using continuity of f at y1 and the proof will follow

Comment: @Dayne $ξ$ is not to be *arbitrarily* chosen, it merely exists as long as $x_3$ and $y_1$ are given. Please *do* look at the links above.

Comment: Same can be argued for the example I have given.